# $3\times 3$ Matrix exponent

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, matrix-exponential

I have a problem where I’m given the matrix
$$
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I’m tasked with computing $e^B$.
Now the point where I’m struggling is how exactly to commence, seeing as $B$ can’t be diagonalized and its Jordan Normal Form is itself. Plugging it into the power series will give me an infinite sum seeing as B isn’t nilpotent.
So how do I compute $e^B$?

Comment: There is a pretty nice pattern for the entries of $B^n$. Did you try computing the first several powers?

Comment: Hint: Write $B=I+N$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $N$ is nilpotent.